# Hive - Convert string like 'yyyy-MM-dd' to date as Datatype 'yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a external table in hive, which has `report_dt` as column and datatype is `string` and has value like   `2018-09-02` `2018-09-03`

And i want to create managed table from the query written on this external table with `report_dt_1` as column with datatype as `date`

i have gone through some threads and i was able to query like

```
create table manag_newtable as select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(report_dt,'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd')) as report_dt_1 from exter_table;
```

so the above query creates a new table, but when i `desc manag_newtable` ,still that `report_dt_1` shows as `string datatype`

Comment: You're converting between the same date format strings?

Comment: the first table has values like '2018-09-03' but its datatype is string, for the new table i want to cast that column as date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Hive 2.1.0, `TO_DATE` returns a string.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Perhaps you want to try a `CAST`.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-date

Otherwise, I suggest leaving the column as epoch time because 1) with your current format you lose timezone information, although you never had it so you are assuming UTC? 2) Hive requires less deserialization time for numbers, making queries faster. If you have to format the epoch, do that at the reporting layer, not the storage layer

Comment: Yes i need to use cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(report_dt,'yyyy-MM-dd'))) as date) which will convert it to date datatype. thanks

Comment: You don't need any of the Unix timestamp functions if the original string is already yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Okay , That makes more sense